# Checking the result of an elementary sum.

Tags: calculus, summation, solution-verification

I'm trying to evaluate $$\sum_{j\geq 0, h\geq 1}a^{j+1}b^{-k}$$
where $b=1-a$ and both $a,b\in (0,1)$. I'm getting

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a^{j+1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{b}\Big)^k=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a ^{j+1}\Big( \frac{b^{-1}}{1-b^{-1}}\Big)=a\Big(\frac{1}{b-1}\Big)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a^j=-\Big(\frac{1}{1-a}\Big)=-\frac{1}{b}$$

yet according to my teacher the sum should equal $1$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: $\sum b^{-k}$ doesn’t converge.

Comment: @Jujustum You are right. Maybe both me and my teacher are wrong?

Comment: Statement seems to have typos k?, h?